# Move Umbraco 4 website to another server - backoffice error

Tags: asp.net, authentication, umbraco, move, umbraco4

I have a Umbraco 4 website on a webserver and when I copy the website to another server the backoffice is not shown.

Login to website on current server - works perfect:

[Ok - Login to Umbraco 4 backoffice](http://thomasthor.net/umbraco_ok_01.png)

[Ok - Umbraco 4 backoffice](http://thomasthor.net/umbraco_ok_02.png)

When I copy the website to another server and logging in to the backoffice:

[Error - Login to Umbraco 4 backoffice](http://thomasthor.net/umbraco_error_01.png)

[Error - Umbraco 4 backoffice](http://thomasthor.net/umbraco_error_02.png)

The login form is align to the left og the backoffice is not shown. I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Have you checked in DevTools (F12) if you get any 404s or other HTTP errors? I'm thinking javascript and/or CSS files might be missing/unreachable.

Comment: try this. set the umbracoConfigurationStatus to "".. startup and thinks are working again. if not check the log in the database

Comment: Also try clearing your local cache and cookies.

Comment: Try to delete all files in App_Data/TEMP folder, and restart your website.